# Determine a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ and determine the multiplication table for $G/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Question: Write down a multiplication table for $G$, the group of symmetries of a square. Determine a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ and determine the multiplication table for $G/N$.
 My problem is doing the multiplication table for symmetries of a square and determining the normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ right now. Once I know that, I can find the last part of the question. Need help

Comment: Well, there is always a lazy option: Take $N=G$, then $N/G$ is the trivial group.

Comment: To start a multiplication table, you need to know how many elements there are, and decide a name for each one. Have you done that?

Comment: @Arthur no because I do not how many elements should be in there like you just said

Answer (score 1):

The symmetry group of the square is the dihedral group $D_4$ with $8$ elements. Every subgroup of index $2$ is normal, so we could take the subgroup $C_4$ generated by a rotation of the sqaure. Then the quotient group $D_4/C_4\cong C_2$ has two elements.

References:

[Table of dihedral group D4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151234/table-of-dihedral-group-d4)

[How to describe all normal subgroups of the dihedral group Dn?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595884/how-to-describe-all-normal-subgroups-of-the-dihedral-group-dn)

Comment: the table of dihedral looks confusing because the comments pointed out many errors on that table

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the answers there correct this, and I am sure you will find several other tables for $D_4$, if you google. Did you find [this one](http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/aaol/grouptables1.html)?